# WPF Master/Detail data binding between 2 combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have two combobox where Parent has to show the list of Countries and the child combo has to show a list of cities of the choosen country.
The data is stored in a `Dictionary<Int32, List<String>>` which has the name `CountriesCitiesList`.
I have the following code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCountriesList" 
    DataContext="{Binding CountriesCitiesList}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox x:Name="cbCitiesList" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                  
          ItemsSource="{Binding CountriesCitiesList}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
</ComboBox>
```

The issue is that in the cities combo i can't show the cities list of the country selected. It feel to me that is missing a final step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your dictionary `CountriesCitiesList` contains country Id as Key and List as cities name, you can bind it in pure xaml way something like this -

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCountriesList"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CountriesCitiesList}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCitiesList"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=cbCountriesList}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

I am assuming you want to show country Id's in cbCountriesList since you are binding it to the dictionary with key of int type.

Answer (score 0):

For the parent ComboBox, bind the `SelectedItem` to a property on your model:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCountriesList" 
    DataContext="{Binding CountriesCitiesList}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"
    ItemSource="{Binding}"
    SelectedItem={Binding Path=SomePropertyOnModel} />
```

Where `SomePropertyOnModel` is of the same type as an Item in the Countries List.

For the child ComboBox, everything should be the same:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbCitiesList" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                  
    ItemsSource="{Binding CountriesCitiesList}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem ="true"
    ItemSource="{Binding}" />
```

*Side Note: You'll notice that I specifically added the ItemsSource binding to both the ComboBoxes.*

In the model, whenever the `SomePropertyOnModel` is set, update the `CountriesCitiesList` based on the value received, i.e.,:

```
private string _somePropertyOnModel;
public string SomePropertyOnModel 
{
    get { return _somePropertyOnModel; }
    set 
    {
        _somePropertyOnModel = value;
        // call NotifyPropertyChanged
        UpdateCountriesCitiesList();
    }
}

private void UpdateCountriesCitiesList()
{
    // set CountriesCitiesList based on the 
    // SomePropertyOnModel value
    // CountriesCitiesList should be an ObservableCollection and the values
    // should be cleared and then added.
    CountriesCitiesList.Clear();
    CountriesCitiesList.Add( "Springfield" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

----------------------------MASTER-------------------------

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="CityCB" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding CitiesList}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="CITYNAME" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

----------------------------DETAIL-------------------------

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="RegionCB" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.REGIONS, ElementName=CityCB}"
    DisplayMemberPath="REGIONNAME" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

In this example i'm illustrating master-detail between City and the Regions which it contains.