# WPF two comboboxes based on the same list

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am fairly new to working with WPF and have this simple scenario which I am looking to implement:

I have two comboboxes, cmbSite and cmbLogFiles and I have a `List<LogFileDirectory>` which is defined as follows:

```
class LogFileDirectory 
{
    public List<System.IO.FileInfo> Files { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Path { get; private set; }

    private LogFileDirectory() { }
    public LogFileDirectory(string name, string path)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Path = path;
        this.Files = new List<System.IO.FileInfo>();
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(this.Path))
        {
            foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(this.Path, "*.log", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                this.Files.Add(new System.IO.FileInfo(file));
        }

    }
}
```

I have cmbSite bound to the **Name** property on the `List<LogFileDirectory>` in the code behind like this:

```
cmbSite.ItemsSource = _logFileInfo.WebServerLogFileDirectories;
cmbSite.SelectedValue = "Path";
cmbSite.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

I would like cmbLogFiles bound to the **Files** property on the same `List<LogFileDirectory>` of the currently selected cmbSite and filtered to the entry LogFileDirectory object for the currently selected value of cmbSite, but I am really not quite sure how to do this without writing code in the ClickEvent handler of cmbSite (which seems like the wrong approach based on my WPF research) and rebinding cmbLogFiles to the select cmbSite LogFileDirectory.

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875887/wpf-master-detail-data-binding-between-2-combobox

Comment: @Chris That was a lot easier than I thought. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the thread that @Chris pointed me to in the comment above, the resolution was simple.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbLogFiles" Width="140" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Files, ElementName=cmbSite}" />
```

Where the ItemsSource property of cmbLogFiles specifies that the Binding will be the **Files** Property off of the SelectedItem object (which is defined as object of **LogFileDirectory**) and specified via the Element attribute to my other combobox (cmbSites).

I was able to remove all of the code behind by setting a DataContext on my window:

```
parserView = new Parser();
parserView.DataContext = new LogFileInfo("deathstar");
```

And then the subsequent XAML of the Parser window:

```
<Window x:Class="Zapora.UI.Parser"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Log File Parser" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label Content="Web Site:"/>
        <ComboBox  Name="cmbSite" Width="180" ItemsSource="{Binding WebServerLogFileDirectories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Path"/>
        <Label Content="Files Available:"/>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbLogFiles" Width="140" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Files, ElementName=cmbSite}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```