# Binding cascading combobox itemsource in wpf datagrid using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

How to bind a 2nd dropdown based on first dropdown selected value of first dropdown using mvvm

Here is the class strcture

```
List<Location> Locations; //Application global cached data 
List<Room> Room; //Application global cached data 
class Location {LocationId, Name ....} 
class Room{RoomId, Name, LocationId...}
```

XAML

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Property Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Name="LocationsComboBox"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Locations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"                
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding PropertyId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<!--Room Number-->
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Room Number">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Name="RoomComboBox"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Rooms, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"               
                  DisplayMemberPath="RoomName" SelectedValuePath="RoomId"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding NewRoomId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.PropertyChangedCommand, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17946.cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx

Comment: @ParameswarRao: That article doesn't use a datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use INotifypropertychanged ? you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged  and change your child list when parent was changed

Comment: How would I get 2nd combobox control to bind in MVVM.

Comment: Yuou Sholud have List<Location> Locations; //Application global cached data 
List<Room> Room; //Application global cached data  and 1 Location it is selectedLocation(or id as you write) bind to your first combobox as selected value, after that implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel so when your selectedvalue SelectedLocation is changing that time you must change your rooms like this Rooms.where(r =>r.LocationId == SelectedLocationId); try to read about mvvm and inotifypropertychanged

Comment: @ShantanuGupta Check Master Detail I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Master Slave/Details way of combo box.
U can find [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875887/wpf-master-detail-data-binding-between-2-combobox)

### But in your Case

The binding for Room ComboBox should be from Code Behind on the basis of selected LocationID.

the below binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Rooms..
```

should be something like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.RoomsInSelectedLocation
```

and in ViewModel

```
IEnumerable<Room> RoomsInSelectedLocation  
{  
     return Rooms.where(r => r.LocationId == SelectedLocationId);  
}
```

evaluate this every time the Location Combo selected item changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use ObservableCollection<Room> instead of List (this will cause the second combobox to update when the first combo box changes the location which in turn causes the room collection to change.

Use ObservableCollection<Location> also.  Your locations might not ever change, but this is simply good MVVM form.