# WPF Make ComboBox selection trigger multiple properties change

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have two classes that have identical Name and Position properties. A ComboBox in a DataGrid has a list of StaffMember class taken from a database. It displays the name only but upon selection both Name and Position properties should change in the DataGrid bound to ObservableCollection of another class - Person.

So far I'm using the SelectionChanged event of the combobox to browse the VisualTree, access parent DataContext and change two properties at a time.

Is there a different approach to it?

Update. Here's an illustrating picture:

[image]

I get the Name and Position from a third party service and display the name in the combobox. As user selects a name the UI should update both Name and Position properties in the table. The table also has Age and many other columns/properties in real world. That is why there are two classes: a name/position list from a database to select from and a class which is the ItemSource of the table. I also have to deal with cases when people have the same name but different positions. Hope this explains the question better.

```
 public class StaffMember : NotifyObject
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }

        private string _position;
        public string Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set { _position = value; OnPropertyChanged("Position"); }
        }

    }

    public class Person : NotifyObject
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }

        private string _position;
        public string Position
        {
            get { return _position; }
            set { _position = value; OnPropertyChanged("Position"); }
        }

        public double Age { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class ViewModel : NotifyObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> SelectedPeople { get; set; }
        public List<StaffMember> Staff { get; set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Staff = new List<StaffMember>
            {
                new StaffMember { Name = "Sigmund Freud", Position = "Psychologist"},
                new StaffMember { Name = "Louis Armstrong", Position = "Musician"},
                new StaffMember { Name = "John Doe", Position = "Superviser"},
                new StaffMember { Name = "John Doe", Position = "Manager"},
            };

            SelectedPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person> {
                new Person { Name = "Sigmund Freud", Position = "123", Age= 161 },
                new Person(),
                new Person() };
        }
    }

    public abstract class NotifyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        public void RaiseProperychanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPeople}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxSelect" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=TheMainWindow, Path=DataContext.Staff}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=DataContext.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                      SelectedValuePath="Name"
                                      SelectionChanged="ComboBoxSelect_SelectionChanged"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
 private void ComboBoxSelect_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
            var parent = sender as DependencyObject;
            while (!(parent is DataGridCell))
            {
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                if (parent is null) return;
            }
            var cell = parent as DataGridCell;
            if (cell == null) return;
            var person = cell.DataContext as Person;
            if (person == null) return;
            person.Position = ((StaffMember)comboBox.SelectedItem).Position.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Am I the only one who don't understand what OP want to achive?

Comment: Your view-model should have a `SelectedPerson` property that the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` is bound to.  Then your `TextBox` for name and position just get bound to `SelectedPerson.Name` and `SelectedPerson.Position`.  You never have to touch the code-behind.

Comment: If your only question is *Is there a different approach to it* then this is far too broad. You're asking for a code review. There's [another site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that.

Comment: I understood you would like to have a cascading combobox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871459/binding-cascading-combobox-itemsource-in-wpf-datagrid-using-mvvm

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to mix MVVM and code-behind. 
You have a duplication of data in Person and StaffMember class.

What about idea of having StaffMember property in Person class?

```
public class StaffMember : NotifyObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    private string _position;
    public string Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; OnPropertyChanged("Position"); }
    }

}

public class Person : NotifyObject
{
    private string _staffMember;
    public string StaffMember
    {
        get { return _staffMember; }
        set { _staffMember = value; OnPropertyChanged("StaffMember"); }
    }

    public double Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @sTrenat Updated

Comment: Making `StaffMember` inherit from `Person` might be a better choice, depending on rest of the business functionality.

Comment: It is another option. It depends on business logic.